# Falstad op amp problems

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm using the Falstad circuits simulator. For some reason, I get a steady 6V input on V- part of the first op amp in a negative feedback connection. When I put another resistor between the voltage source and the op amp, the V- suddenly goes to around zero as it should be.

I don't understand why in the first picture instead of 0 volts at V- I get the whole 6 volts. Perhaps I missed something.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I don't get the zero voltage at V- when the voltage of the input is near the saturation voltage of the op amp.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I don't understand why in the first picture instead of 0 Volts at V- I
> get the whole 6 Volts. Perhaps I miss something.*

In your first picture, you have defined the inverting input voltage to be 6 volts by placing the voltage source without a series resistor. How can you expect it be anything other than 6 volts?

> *my second question, when the voltage reaches saturation of the op amp.
> I understand that it is a "problematic" voltage.*

It's very much problematic in that the op-amp output can no-longer act to keep the non-inverting input at 0 volts.

Comment: You are right. But I'm confused about the fact, that in negative feedback V- should be zero if V+ is grounded

Comment: The "hard" 6 volts placed at the input destroys the negative feedback.

Comment: May explain why?

Comment: 6 volts remains 6 volts no matter what you try to do to it. Ideal voltage sources trump impedance except in the illegal condition where the loading impedance is zero ohms.

Comment: Thank you, sir!

Comment: @KrtekUser if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: About my second question, when the voltage reaches saturation of the op amp. I understand that it is a "problematic" voltage.

Comment: It problematic in that the op-amp output can no-longer act to keep the non-inverting input at 0 volts.

Comment: Thank you very much!